# Cannot download "internal" SNAPSHOT artefacts from Apache archiva

Tags: maven, repository, maven-3, snapshot, archiva

I am using maven 3.0 and Apache Archiva as remote internal repository (configured as mirrior in settings.xml) but I am having problems downloading SNAPSHOT artifacts.

Failed to execute goal on project IntegrationTests: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.br.bigdata:IntegrationTests:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.br.bigdata:HBaseSchema:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in archiva.default (.../archiva/repository/internal/) -> [Help 1]

I checked similar posts here but couldn't resolve my problem.

I checked the Archiva repository, artifact is present, correct pom versions etc.
In my pom the  dependency is specified:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>HBaseSchema</artifactId>
        <version>${version.hbaseSchema}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The artifact pom:

```
<groupId>com.br.bigdata</groupId>
<artifactId>HBaseSchema</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>HBaseSchema</name>
<description>Logical HBase schema</description>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted. This needs to be added to settings.xml

```
    <mirror>
  <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
  <mirrorOf>snapshots</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

and

```
<profile>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>internal</id>
          <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
          <url>https://lab-insighttc:8080/archiva/repository/internal</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
          <url>https://lab-insighttc:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</profile>
```